# Centroid under the Chebyshev distance

Tags: algorithms, normed-spaces

I want to find the centroid (point which minimizes the sum of distances) of a set of points in the $2$-dimensional plane using the Chebyshev distance ($\bf{L}_\infty$ norm). I think the answer is not as simple as the $\bf{L}_2$ norm (which is simply the mean of the $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates).

I read in the wiki article on [Manhattan distances](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Manhattan_distance) that

> A circle of radius r for the Chebyshev distance (L∞ metric) on a plane
> is also a square with side length 2r parallel to the coordinate axes,
> so planar Chebyshev distance can be viewed as equivalent by rotation
> and scaling to planar taxicab distance. However, this equivalence
> between L1 and L∞ metrics does not generalize to higher dimensions.

This would suggest that taking the median in the rotated co-ordinates would give the centroid under Chebyshev distances. However, I don't think all the grid points are mapped to grid points under this $45^\circ$ rotations. Does this matter?

Comment: What grid points?  Yes, minimizing the sum of $L_\infty$ distances of points in the plane corresponds to minimizing the sum of $L_1$ distances after rotating by 45 degrees, and this can be obtained by medians in the rotated coordinates.

Comment: This might be a duplicate. Check this answer:
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/708873/222804

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3817965/339790