# What minimizes the Chebyshev Distance?

Tags: optimization, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

For an arbitrary number of dimensions, I know that the mean minimizes the distance using the $L_2$ norm and that the geometric median minimizes the distance function using the $L_1$ norm (though I have yet to find a good proof of this). So what minimizes the $L_{\infty}$ (or Chebyshev) norm?

[[Context](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/708550)]

Answer (score 3):

The [mid-range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range) minimizes the $\:L_{\hspace{.02 in}\infty}\:$ norm.

Comment: So how do I know that this is correct?

Comment: Look at the distance from points above the mid-range to the smallest value, then look at the distance from points below the mid-range to the largest value. $\;$

Comment: @RicyDemer Not sure what you are trying to show or what you are getting at.

Comment: Observe that all those distances are at least half the [range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(statistics)), so no point can make the $\:L_{\hspace{.02 in}\infty}\:$ norm smaller than half the range. $\;\;$ Since the mid-range makes the $\:L_{\hspace{.02 in}\infty}\:$ norm equal to half the range, the mid-range minimizes the $\:L_{\hspace{.02 in}\infty}\:$ norm. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Can you state in this is a non-confusing way?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}\;$